# How to force activate when using routes with same module id in durandal?

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0

**So this is how i build my routes**

```
[{
        route: 'Phone/:isWidget',
        moduleId: 'commonLog',
        title: 'phoneTitle',
        nav: true,
        hash: '#Phone',
        settings: { Communication: true }
},
{
        route: 'Letters/:isWidget',
        moduleId: 'commonLog',
        title: 'lettertitle',
        nav: true,
        hash: '#Letters',
        settings: { Communication: true }
}]
```

What i need to do is force the activate method to fire when ever i route between them.

**Why would i need that?**

In the activate method i pull the activeInstruction and get route information and depending on that i change my observables and call different api to get the right data and also generate the right columns for my table.

Answer (score 1):

In the `commonLog` module, you need to set a `canReuseForRoute` attribute that is a function that returns `false`.  If your module is a singleton:

```
return {
    // ...
    canReuseForRoute: function () {
        return false;
    },
    // ...
}
```

If your module is a constructor function:

```
return function () {
    // ...
    this.canReuseForRoute = function () {
        return false;
    };
    // ...
};
```

Then the `activate` method will be called every time.

Documentation link: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html - see section "Module Reuse".